# Java - Create Multiple Subfolders at Once

Tags: java, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to create a function that creates multiple folder/subfolders in a single instruction using Java.
I can use `File`'s `mkdirs()` method to create a single folder and its parents.

An example of the struture I want:

```
folder
└── subfolder
    ├── subsubfolder1
    ├── subsubfolder2
    └── subsubfolder3
```

For example in linux I can achieve this with the following command:

```
mkdir -p folder/subfolder/{subsubfolder1,subsubfolder2,subsubfolder3}
```

Is there a way I can achieve this in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if such a method exists, but you can certainly define one:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test {

  public static boolean createDirectoriesWithCommonParent(
      File parent, String...subs) {

    parent.mkdirs();
    if (!parent.exists() || !parent.isDirectory()) {
      return false;
    }

    for (String sub : subs) {
      File subFile = new File(parent, sub);
      subFile.mkdir();
      if (!subFile.exists() || !subFile.isDirectory()) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     createDirectoriesWithCommonParent(new File("test/foo"), "a", "b", "c");
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what I wanted. I'll change the question for a better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

We can create a directory or multiple directories Using Path in Simple step:

```
public static Path createDirectories() throws IOException {
    String folderPath = "E://temp/user/UserId/profilePicture";
    Path path = Paths.get(folderPath);
    return Files.createDirectories(path);
}
```

Path, Paths and Files classes can be found java.nio.file.*; package which is given below :

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

**Note :-** Make sure method should throws IOException or within try-catch.